# mutate_at using multiple conditons

Tags: r, dplyr

I would to transform the columns that contain 1 or 2 in their names of my dataframe `test` by dividing them by the column `Unit`.

It seems to work with one conditions but I do not know how to add the condition `OR 1`

```
 test= test%>% mutate_at(vars(contains('2')), funs(./Unit))
```

any idea?

```
Identifier Source 196001     200006  Unit
1:     top    HH   NA        NA      1e-06
2:     top2   BB   NA        4569.6  1e+00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
test = read.table(header = T,text="
Identifier Source 196001     200006  Unit
top        HH     65         888     3
top2       BB     0111       9886    8") #I modified your values so you can see the divisions

test %>% mutate_at(vars(contains('2'), contains('1')), funs(./Unit))
```

Basically you say "select variables that contain 2, oh and also select variables than contain 1".

If you wanted to select variables that contain 1 AND 2, this would be a different problem and might require regexp (with `dplyr::match`).

Also, please note that `funs` is soft-deprecated, you should now use lambda functions:

```
test = test %>% mutate_at(vars(contains('2'), contains('1')), ~./Unit)
```

Comment: I get an error : Evaluation error: object 'Unit' not found. while the variable Unit is in test. any suggestion?

Comment: Could you share  the head of your dataset? (`dput(head(test))`)

Comment: @richpiana the output you added to your question did not come from `dput`, hence I cannot load your exact dataset to do some tests. As far as I can see it should have worked, as the code above works pretty well. I need the `dput` to tell why you got the error for sure. Moreover, you said it worked with only one column so you didn't get an error then?

Comment: i re-installed the package and now it works, apologies. many thanks for your great help